# How can I convert a JavaScript item comparator script into a React application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have written a JavaScript script that simulates an "Item Comparator" where a user is able to create a ranked list through a series of user inputs.

I am trying to build a simple React application that translates this logic into a user interface. However, as I am new to React, I am having trouble getting a functioning app and I fear I am not using the right approach. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the JavaScript code that contains the logic I am trying to replicate:

```
const readline = require('readline-sync');

const items = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];

let rankedListCount = 1;

// For each item, use a binary search approach to determine its spot in the list
for (let i = 1; i < items.length; i++) {
  const item = items[i];
  console.log(`Comparing ${item} to the existing list...`);
  
  let left = 0;
  let right = i - 1;
  
  while (left <= right) {
    const mid = Math.floor((left + right) / 2);
    const comparison_item = items[mid];
    const preference = readline.question(`Do you prefer ${item} or ${comparison_item}? Enter 1 or 2: `);
    
    if (preference === "1") {
      right = mid - 1;
    } else {
      left = mid + 1;
    }
  }
  
  const index = left;
  items.splice(i, 1);
  items.splice(index, 0, item);
  rankedListCount++;

  console.log(`Inserted ${item} at position ${index}\n`);
  console.log("Your current ranking of the items is:");
for (let i = 0; i < rankedListCount; i++) {
  console.log(`${i+1}) ${items[i]}`);
}
}

console.log("Your final ranking of the items is:");
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  console.log(`${i+1}) ${items[i]}`);
}
```

This is the current state of my React code. I am expecting the user to be able to push buttons to complete comparisons and have the ranked list update in real time.

At first, my options are to "Select which item is better:" and there are buttons that say B and A and a ranked list A-E. If I click one of the buttons, nothing happens.

If I click it again, the contents of the buttons disappear and so does the ranked list.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const ItemComparator = () => {
  const [rankedItemList, setRankedItemList] = useState(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']);
  const [rankedItemsCount, setRankedItemsCount] = useState(1);
  const [primaryItem, setPrimaryItem] = useState(rankedItemList[1]);
  const [comparisonItem, setComparisonItem] = useState(rankedItemList[0]);
  const [leftIndex, setLeftIndex] = useState(0);
  const [rightIndex, setRightIndex] = useState(rankedItemsCount-1);
  const [midIndex, setMidIndex] = useState(Math.floor((leftIndex + rightIndex) / 2));

  function handleSelection(preferredItem) {
    if (preferredItem === 'primary') {
      setRightIndex(midIndex-1);
    } else {
      setLeftIndex(midIndex+1);
    }

    if (leftIndex > rightIndex) {
      setRankedItemList(rankedItemList.splice(rankedItemsCount, 1));
      setRankedItemList(rankedItemList.splice(leftIndex, 0, primaryItem));
      setRankedItemsCount(rankedItemsCount+1);
      setPrimaryItem(rankedItemList[rankedItemsCount]);
      setLeftIndex(0);
      setRightIndex(rankedItemsCount-1);
      setMidIndex(Math.floor((leftIndex + rightIndex) / 2));
      setComparisonItem(rankedItemList[midIndex]);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Item Comparator</h1>
      <p>Select which item is better:</p>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => handleSelection('primary')}>{rankedItemList[rankedItemsCount]}</button>
        <button onClick={() => handleSelection('comparison')}>{rankedItemList[midIndex]}</button>
      </div>
      <h2>Comparison List</h2>
      <ol>
        <li>{rankedItemList[0]}</li>
        <li>{rankedItemList[1]}</li>
        <li>{rankedItemList[2]}</li>
        <li>{rankedItemList[3]}</li>
        <li>{rankedItemList[4]}</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ItemComparator;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are misunderstanding how `useState` is working. You can not just use it as a reference value.

Every time you call a state-setter (eg `setRankedItemList`) you are updating the react state.

by calling

```
setRankedItemList(rankedItemList.splice(rankedItemsCount, 1));
setRankedItemList(rankedItemList.splice(leftIndex, 0, primaryItem));
```

You are overwriting the `rankedItemList` state twice. React is "smart" to bundle state updates for performance improvements which is why you are seeing some weird behaviour.

In order to get the behaviour you expect you can just work with local or reference values inside of your `handleSelection` method.

For example `leftIndex` and `rightIndex` can just be a constant which is calculated each time you call the `handleSelection` method like:

```
function handleSelection(preferredItem) {
  let leftIndex = 0;
  let rightIndex = rankedItemsCount - 1;

  if (preferredItem === "primary") {
    rightIndex = midIndex - 1
  } else {
    leftIndex = midIndex + 1
  }

  // ...rest
}
```

Also the new ranked items should be calculated once before updating the state again

```
function handleSelection(preferredItem) {
  // ...calculating indexes
  
  const newRankedItems = []

  // ... your logic to set the newRankedItems

  setRankedItemList(newRankedItems) // Just a single call to update the state
}
```

Also the way you handle displaying the `rankedItemList` is not the way you should do this in `react` check out [the docs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)